# Mock jQuery method call on an object created inside function under test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, sinon

I'm creating a jQuery object inside a function that I'm testing. I need to mock the `prop` method call.

How can I do this? I'm using Jest. I tried with Sinon as well, but I couldn't get this working.

Here's my method:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

export function myFunc(element) {
  var htmlControl = $(element);
  var tagName = htmlControl.prop('tagName');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution using `sinonjs`:

`index.ts`:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

export function myFunc(element) {
  var htmlControl = $(element);
  var tagName = htmlControl.prop('tagName');
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('myFunc', () => {
  it('should mock prop() method', () => {
    const el = {};
    const propStub = sinon.stub().returnsThis();
    const jqueryStub = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => {
      return {
        prop: propStub
      };
    });
    const { myFunc } = proxyquire('./', {
      jquery: jqueryStub
    });
    myFunc(el);
    expect(jqueryStub.calledWith(el)).to.be.true;
    expect(propStub.calledWith('tagName')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 myFunc
    ✓ should mock prop() method (156ms)


  1 passing (161ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57461604